# CoreAnimation with UIImage

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to make a Core Animation in `Xcode` using a png image. So far I got the box to slide across the screen on load using `CGRectMake` to draw a small box and it works. Now i am going to replace the `CGRect` line with a `layer.contents = [UIImage imageNamed:@""];` type line. Any help? Thanks.

(rest of working code :))

.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

{
CAShapeLayer * layer;
UIImage * new; //hypothetical image

}

@end
```

.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end


@implementation ViewController




//[self view]

- (void)viewDidLoad
{   //layer
layer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
layer.position = CGPointMake ([self view].bounds.size.width /2, [self view].bounds.size.height    /2 );
layer.bounds= CGRectMake (0,0,100,100);
layer.borderWidth = 2;
layer.borderColor = [[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1 ] CGColor] ;


[[[self view] layer] addSublayer: layer];



CABasicAnimation * moveAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position.y"];
moveAnimation.duration = 1;
//starting point for the animation
moveAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:layer.position.y];
//end point for the animation
moveAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:layer.position.y + 100];
//this line makes the animation stay to its position after moving
layer.position = CGPointMake(layer.position.x, layer.position.y +100);


[layer addAnimation:moveAnimation forKey: @"move1"];





[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
```

}

```
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Finally got it to work after adding the line

```
UIImage *image2 = [[UIImage alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                                          pathForResource:@"pic@2x" ofType:@"png"]];
```

right above the layer as well as specifying the suggested bride cast. Here's the final code for the did load method.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
UIImage *image2 = [[UIImage alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                                          pathForResource:@"pic@2x" ofType:@"png"]];
layer = [CALayer layer];
layer.contents = (__bridge id)image2.CGImage;
layer.position = CGPointMake ([self view].bounds.size.width /2, [self view].bounds.size.height /3 );
layer.bounds= CGRectMake (100,100,500,500);
[[[self view] layer] addSublayer: layer];


CABasicAnimation * moveAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position.y"];
moveAnimation.duration = 1;

moveAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:layer.position.y];
moveAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:layer.position.y + 100];

layer.position = CGPointMake(layer.position.x, layer.position.y +100);


[layer addAnimation:moveAnimation forKey: @"move1"];



[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
```

}

Comment: What are you asking here? It doesn't make sense to replace the contents of a shape layer with an image. Why not just use an image view and move that? Are you asking how to set an image as the contents of a basic CALayer?

Comment: Yes. To be clear I am asking how to set a layers contents (layer.contents) to a .png image. Good point, at runtime I will change the CAshape layer to a CALAyer if that helps.

Comment: what about the layers contents?

Comment: If my answer helped you (and it looks like it did) then the standard process is to accept the answer, rather than update the question. You do this by checking the green tick mark by the answer. This gives you rep and lets others know the question is answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a layer's contents to a UIImage like this:

```
layer.contents = (__bridge id)image.CGImage;
```

A layer takes a `CGImageRef` (core graphics image reference) for its contents - this is to allow compatibility between OS X and iOS. You therefore want to pass in the `CGImage` property of the `UIImage` object, which is `image` in the line above. `NSImage` on OS X has the same property.

However,  a CGImageRef is not an `NSObject`, but a core foundation type. The `(__bridge id)` is a *bridging cast* which you can use to enable the compiler to treat it as an `NSObject`. You can read more about these principles by searching for bridging casts or toll-free bridging, but it's outside the scope of this answer.

You probably should do this to a base CALayer rather than a shape layer. A shape layer wants to make its own contents from the path you've given it.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. Recompiling in progress.. Would you mind helping me fit the line of code you posted with 'Image2' as the path for the hypothetical image? I've never seen

Comment: '_bridge id' before or 'CGImage' for that matter. I was expecting something like this layer.contents = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image2"];...

Comment: Also would the .h need to be modified? Thx

Comment: I would only have to replace the layer.bounds= CGRectMake (0,0,100,100); line of code with layer.contents = (__bridge id)image.CGImage; right m8?

Comment: I've edited the answer to explain more about how it works. You should be able to work it out from there.